# How to convert an endmember collection spectral signature file from OLI sensor to TM and ETM+ sensors

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, envi

I'm working on some supervised classifications using scenes from the landsat legacy archive wich include ETM+, TM 5 and OLI data from 2001 to 2014. I have training and validation points for each scene for the different classes I have defined. Because of this, the fact that every scene is different on its own, and that the bands used in each classification vary in spetral resolution from one sensor to the other, I want to apply the spectral signature defined for the OLI scene (because it's the newest and I can actually go and validate it in the field) to the other scenes as well.

I'm working with ENVI 4.8 and 5.1, using the MLC classifier. Is there a tool in ENVI that can "translate" the spectral signature made from the OLI data to the other sensors?

Answer (score 1):

For an analysis like this, you need to atmospherically correct the images and convert to surface reflectance. You will also want to make sure the images were acquired at approximately the same time period to take into account seasonal variability. There are a variety of resources available for atmospheric correction.  ENVI has a [Atmospheric Correction Module](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/AboutAtmosphericCorrectionModule.html) that may be of use to you. I would highly recommend reading the following article on the subject:

[Song, C., Woodcock, C. E., Seto, K. C., Lenney, M. P., & Macomber, S. A. (2001). Classification and change detection using Landsat TM data: when and how to correct atmospheric effects?. Remote sensing of Environment, 75(2), 230-244.](http://www.unc.edu/courses/2007spring/geog/577/001/www/Song01_RSE.pdf)